# How to make bach file variables run scripts

Tags: lauterbach

I'm not very good at coding (probably because I came from using MIT scratch), and I want to know if you can create a variable:
set Var=(a random line of code)
And have it so that when I tell it to echo the variable, it will run the code:
echo Var
and say if I set Var=cls, then it would run CLS and clear the screen. What can I do, as maybe an alternative, or what....?

Pls help,

Thanks,
    -Hilton

Comment: It's very unclear for me what you are actually trying to do. For starters: Which programming language are you using? On which platform your code should run? Are you talking about Windows/MSDOS Batch files? Or do you want to write scripts for Lauterbach TRACE32?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really store code in environment variables. It would make more sense to have a folder full of tools that you use. You can add the folder to your system path so that when you type the name of one of the files it can be found without the need to specify a full path.